# How to highlight a row of my table

Tags: php, mysql, css

How can I highlight the background color of a row of a table I print this way when I read it's contents from a database? Sometimes two rows. The condition to highlight is the value of the 3rd column.

```
<?php               
echo "<table id='allocation' class='inlineTable'>";  //style='border: solid 1px black;'
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th class=\"row-1 a_user\">User </th>";
echo "<th class=\"row-2 a_destination\">User </th>";
echo "<th class=\"row-3 a_tremaining\">Time Remaining </th>";
echo "<col = width: 3em />";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<col = width: 3em />";
class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
    function __construct($it) { 
     parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    }
    function current() {
     return "<td style='width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }
    function beginChildren() {
     echo "<tr>";
    }
    function endChildren() {
     echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }       
}           

$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "mydb";
$user = 'root';
$port = 3306;

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=$port;dbname=$dbname", $user);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);         
    $sql_fetch = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_ID, destination, trem FROM reservation_table");
    $sql_fetch->execute();
    $result = $sql_fetch->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(new TableRows2(new RecursiveArrayIterator($sql_fetch->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

echo "</table>";
$conn = null;
?>
```

May I please seek your help? I want to highlight or blink the row when the value in `trem` (third column) reaches 00:00. My css right now is very basic/simple : https://jsfiddle.net/8Lfj3h0j/

Really need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since i cannot yet comment, i am going to ask it this way. Can you please be a bit more specific. The trem value looks like a counter. So what you want to do is checking the value of the row with javascript, and if the value is 00.00 you change the css class with javascript.

```
$('#elementId').toggleClass('yourCSSclass');
```

If this is not what you mean then by all means feel free to correct me or clarify your question:)

EDIT:
in your php function "current" you can check if the value is 00.00 with an if statement. call a javascript function if the value is 00.00 
it should look like this:

```
function current() {
if(parent::current()=="00.00"){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , '$('#elementId').toggleClass('yourCSSclass');'
   , '</script>'
;}else{}
     return "<td style='width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }
```

note: i have little experience with the RecursiveIterator classes so i can not tell with certaincy that parent::current()=="00.00" will work, but you should get the general idea of checking the value and calling the js function.

EDIT:
copy pasted from comment

```
<?php

 $i=0; while($array=sqlsrv_fetch_array($data)){ 
 $counterVariable=parent::current();
  //not sure if the above line works this is just theory
 ?>
 <tr data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
      <td><?php echo $array['Product_id']; ?></td> 
      <td><?php echo $array['Product_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $counterVariable ?></td> 
</tr> 
<?php $i=$i+1; }?>
```

Comment: Hi @ThrowingDwarf, I have not yet implmented the countdown timer yet, as I do not yet know how to do that. I was hoping to do something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/htsm45x4/ But I am unsure how to print the countdown clock on the third column and then highlight the row when my time is up.

Comment: i tried it with the jsfiddle but somehow it wont let me change the color through javascript this is strange..

Comment: how would you do it if you were me? : ( 

I found another example for timer perhaps we can use : https://jsfiddle.net/14b76gnt/

Even if I couldnt change the color now, what I am looking for now is a way to print the countdown clock on the last column of each row.

Comment: personally i would echo an entire row at a time (no functions for <td> etc.), This way i can generate each row and give them a "data-id" parameter which i can give a value (this essentially functions as an id). then you can echo the timer value in the last cell/td. This way you dont need fancy code to check every row.

Comment: while($array=sqlsrv_fetch_array($data)){
                
                ?>
                                <tr data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                    <td><?php echo $array['Product_id']; ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $arrXIV['Product_name']; ?></td>

                                       <td class="tdC"><?php echo $counterVariable ?></td>
                                      
                                </tr>
           <?php
           $i=$i+1;
           
            }

Comment: good to know that it is solved now :) maybe you can clear up my kinda messy answer :p and delete the parts that are irrelevant for the solution ;p

Answer (score 0):

```
 #allocation tr:nth-child(3n+3) {  
      color: #ccc;
    }
```

Use this css for every 3rd column highlighted.